# Error : Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am unable to get value from Android to Java desktop Server. I only get one output. I have made the loop to run it 5 times. It runs one time and give output on android once and then it crashes. It should give output to android 5 times. And after each output it should pass value to java desktop server.

What I am doing and What I want actually : I am getting signal strength at a point. I want 5 samples of it. So I run the code 5 times. As soon as I get the value one time, I wiant to pass it to the Java Desktop Server code. I have written the in java as server.java and it runs perfectly fine.

Client Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
        protected static final long TIME_DELAY = 1000;
        TextView mTextView;
        private WifiManager wifiManager;
        Handler handler=new Handler();  
        int count =0; String data ="";

        private String messsage;

        private static final IntentFilter FILTER = new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_id);          
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);         
            wifiManager.startScan();

        }


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Register the scan receiver
            registerReceiver(scanReceiver, FILTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            // Unregister the receiver
            unregisterReceiver(scanReceiver);
        }

        public void onClickRefresh(View v) {
            count=0;
            wifiManager.startScan();

            //Log.d(TAG, "onClickRefresh");
        }


        BroadcastReceiver scanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //  Log.d(TAG, "scanReceiver received!");
                // Refreshes the chart once we have scan results

                // Request a scan again

                if(count<5){
                 final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                 List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                 for (ScanResult result : wifiScanList) {
                        if (result.SSID.equals("Khosla ka Ghosla")) {
                            sb.append(""+result.level);
                        }
                        if (result.SSID.equals("panny")) {
                            sb.append(""+result.level);
                        }
                        if (result.SSID.equals("ferbora")) {
                            sb.append(""+result.level);
                        }   

                  //      mTextView.setText("getting called " +count + sb);                   
                        messsage=sb.toString();
                        mTextView.setText(messsage);

                    } count++;
                    new Asynctask1().execute(messsage);
                wifiManager.startScan();
                }
            }
        };

          public class Asynctask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
              private PrintWriter printwriter;
            private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.8";  
            private static final int DEST_PORT = 4444;
            private EditText mTextField;
            protected Void doInBackground(String... messages) {
                String message = messages[0];
                Socket client = null;
                try {
                    client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Write to server.
                try {
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream
                    printwriter.flush();
                    printwriter.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        client.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

The error I get is nullpointer exception. I dont know why it is having null. It gives the error in:  finally { try {client.close();.

The log cat does not show much thing except this. Can you please guide me.

Comment: @NiksTyagi Yes, I am able to connect with the server. If I just write the Asynctask then I am able to print to the Server. But not when I run the code 5 times and when I kept the loop. So server is fine. Dont know, why this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

you are return null in the doInBackground method.

Comment: I had this code running when I had removed broadcast receiver. So, I am not sure.

Comment: but if the method is void why you return a null value

Comment: If I dont add null it tells me to add a return type..it is Void (V caps)